# Nash Equilibria and Load Balancing Game

Tags: complexity-theory, game-theory

I know that the Nash Equilibria is where no one of my players can change his state to get a better situation. I got m machines (same speed , infinite capacity) and n agents (players) , every agent has a weight w that he has to process using a machine. The individual goal of every agent is to minimize the load of her machine. The global goal is to minimize the makespan. I need to prove that starting by any solution i can converge to a pure Nash Equilibria.

( Assuming machines < agents) If I sort my agents by decreasing weight and assigning  each of them a machine :

```
m1
m2

a1 = 3
a2 = 5
a3 = 7

load m1 = 7
load m2 = 5+3 = 8
```

is this a pure nash equilibria ? No one of my agents wants to change his state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have assigned agents to machines. Each agent a<sub>i</sub> has work w<sub>i</sub> to do, and each machine m<sub>j</sub> has a total load L<sub>j</sub> (which is the sum of the loads of the agents assigned to it).

If agent a<sub>i</sub> has been assigned to machine m<sub>j</sub>, and changes to machine m<sub>k</sub>, the new loads will be:

L<sub>j</sub>' = L<sub>j</sub> - w<sub>i</sub>
L<sub>k</sub>' = L<sub>k</sub> + w<sub>i</sub>

Agent a<sub>i</sub> will want this if and only if L<sub>k</sub>' < L<sub>j</sub>

Now define a new quantity, R, which is the sum of the squares of L, and see how it changes:

R' - R = (L<sub>j</sub>'<sup>2</sup> + L<sub>k</sub>'<sup>2</sup>) - (L<sub>j</sub><sup>2</sup> + L<sub>k</sub><sup>2</sup>)
= (L<sub>j</sub> -
w<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (L<sub>k</sub> +
w<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup> - (L<sub>j</sub><sup>2</sup> + L<sub>k</sub><sup>2</sup>)
= (-2L<sub>j</sub>w<sub>i</sub> + w<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>) + (2L<sub>k</sub> w<sub>i</sub> + w<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>)
= -2L<sub>j</sub>w<sub>i</sub> + (2L<sub>k</sub> w<sub>i</sub> + 2w<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>)
= 2w<sub>i</sub> [ -L<sub>j</sub> + (L<sub>k</sub> + w<sub>i</sub>)]
= 2w<sub>i</sub> [ -L<sub>j</sub> + L<sub>k</sub>']

But we already know that L<sub>k</sub>' < L<sub>j</sub>, so

R' - R < 0

R is non-negative (because it is a sum of squares), it will *decrease* with each change, and it will decrease by an amount whose minimum is greater than zero. *Therefore this process cannot continue for an infinite number of steps.* Therefore it will reach a state in which no agent wants to change machines.